# how to link to specify glibc

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, linker, glibc

I have a cmake project that need to be linked with glibc-2.33. As system glibc is low version and install new glibc to system is not recommended, I build and install glibc-2.33 following with #2 in [http://web.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/kml/how_to_build_and_use_glibc.html](http://web.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Etosh/kml/how_to_build_and_use_glibc.html) into a custom path. but I'm not sure how to add cmake sentence so that I can link the project with glibc-2.33 (should be linker and all libraries). Maybe someone can give me some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm not sure how to add cmake sentence so that I can link the project with glibc-2.33 (should be linker and all libraries).

The example you referenced *doesn't require* you to link against the new GLIBC, and instead uses "explicit loader invocation" -- `/path/to/ld.so /path/to/binary` *at runtime*.

If you do want to link against the new GLIBC, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617). Sorry I don't know how to do this with `cmake`.